boto3 - get request headers?
Anyone know how to get the request object headers from boto3?
For example:
client = boto3.client('cognito-identity', region_name=aws_session.region_name)

response = client.get_id(
    IdentityPoolId=amplify_outputs['auth']['identity_pool_id'],
)

response result:
{'IdentityId': 'us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '48a7f4f9-52aa-49b2-b150-e0722dd15319',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Wed, 22 May 2024 12:40:12 GMT',
   'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
   'content-length': '63',
   'connection': 'keep-alive',
   'x-amzn-requestid': '48a7f4f9-52aa-49b2-b150-e0722dd15319',
   'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}

The reason I ask, is I'm trying to test some enpoints using HTTP.
I can't find any traces for identity provider in cloud watch or cognito console, and I have yet be able to get the request from the boto3 client.

Enable debug logging.

The interactions of boto3 and AWS are the same as AWSCLI and AWS. Boto3 just translates your code to API calls.
So you can do the same API query in AWSCLI using a bash terminal, and use a traffic sniffer to capture the packages.
I would follow this tutorial --> https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/knowledge-base/capturing-aws-traffic
And here you have the AWSCLI command of your example code --> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/get-id.html
